# Use Mock in Jest test for rendering element in screen and find them with "findAllBy" method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

So basically I'm trying to use a mock that I made with fake data for test some components. It was all fine but when I was trying to make use of the "findAllByRole" method it just return me an empty object and throws me an error telling me that all the items with the role "listitem" don't exist.

MainSection.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import MainSection from './MainSection.js';
import { getItems } from '../../Database/Database.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import mockProducts from '../../Database/mockProducts.js';

jest.mock('axios');

beforeEach(() => {
    render(<MainSection />);
});

test('Check if renders all the 20 items in the MainSection', async () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        data: mockProducts,
    });

    await getItems();

    const allBoxes = screen.findAllByRole('listitem');

    expect(allBoxes).toHaveLength(20);
});
```

MainSection.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
import FiltersBox from './FiltersBox/FiltersBox.js';
import { getItems } from '../../Database/Database.js';
import './MainSection.css';

function MainSection() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems().then(res => setItems(res));
    }, []);

    return (
        <section>
            <article className='items_container-main'>
                <div className='items_container' role='list'>
                    items.map(item => (
                            <div
                                className='item_box'
                                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})` }}
                                key={item.id}
                                role='listitem'>
                                <div className='item_box-data_container'>
                                    <div className='item_box-data_container-price_star'>
                                        <div className='item_box-price'>${item.price}</div>
                                    <div className='item_box-title'>{item.title}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    );
}

export default MainSection;
```

Database.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export async function getItems() {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error! D:', error);
    }
}
```

Error

[image: error message]

All my files (if you need it)

[image: files]

**I think that's the reason of that error, because I need to make the test use that mock with fake data as an API response data, but I don't know how can I do it...**

Comment: Can you show the `MainSection` component code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @LinDu Sure, I didn't do it before because the code in MainSection.js is a bit extense, but I will edit my question right now.

Comment: Can you make a minimal, reproducible example? Remove the unrelated part of the code. So that we can locate the issue easily.

Comment: @LinDu Done. So sorry... I'm a bit new at this yet. I think the code should run fine without all the things I removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need to mock the entire `axios` module using `jest.mock('axios')`, you can just mock `axios.get()` method.
- You should render the component after mocking the `axios.get()`.
- You should use `await screen.findAllByRole('listitem')` to [waiting for appearance](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance)

`MainSection.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getItems } from './Database';

function MainSection() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  console.log(" ~ file: MainSection.jsx:6 ~ MainSection ~ items:", items)

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems().then((res) => setItems(res));
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <article className="items_container-main">
        <div className="items_container" role="list">
          {items.map((item) => {
            return <div key={item.id} role='listitem'>{item.title}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
}

export default MainSection;
```

`MainSection.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MainSection from './MainSection';
import axios from 'axios';

test('Check if renders all the 20 items in the MainSection', async () => {
  const axiosGetSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValue({
    data: [
      { id: 1, title: 'a' },
      { id: 2, title: 'b' },
    ],
  });
  render(<MainSection />);
  const allBoxes = await screen.findAllByRole('listitem');
  expect(allBoxes).toHaveLength(2);
  axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75539392/MainSection.test.jsx (9.547 s)
  ✓ Check if renders all the 20 items in the MainSection (96 ms)

  console.log
     ~ file: MainSection.jsx:6 ~ MainSection ~ items: []

      at MainSection (stackoverflow/75539392/MainSection.jsx:6:11)

  console.log
     ~ file: MainSection.jsx:6 ~ MainSection ~ items: [ { id: 1, title: 'a' }, { id: 2, title: 'b' } ]

      at MainSection (stackoverflow/75539392/MainSection.jsx:6:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.348 s, estimated 12 s
```

Comment: Nice, it worked! Thank you so much! Also I deleted the "beforeEach" function because it was rendering the MainSection without using the mock for render the elements inside and obviously throwing me an error. I recommend you write that in your points too :)

Comment: @Kosh Yes, you need to make sure to run the code after creating the mock object.